# Simplification of the derivative of the mean curvature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, curvature, runge-kutta-methods

I'm using the RK method to calculate the thin film profile. there is a complex interface curvature term, as shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RFfU.png), κ. The final formula is a fourth-order ordinary differential equation which requires the first and second curvature derivative terms, they are also listed in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RFfU.png). However, I don't understand how it was simplified. Specifically, I don't know where does ln(r) come from. Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: You are right to be stumped by this, there should have been used the derivative term giving $-\frac{\delta'}{r^2}$, not the anti-derivative of $\frac1r$. This seems to be a mental hang-up as in the next step again an anti-derivative or integral is used in the product derivative instead of a derivative.

Comment: Thanks, it could be a mistake. But this formula not only published and peer-reviewed, but also included in a PhD dissertation.

Comment: It makes no sense, as this sequence of equations is only about differentiation of the $\kappa$ term. In a variational context one could get such a see-saw of differentiation and integration via partial integration, but that is not in play here.